# Find out the time zone of timestamp coming from API

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am always confused with the time zones.

I have a timestamp **2021-01-20T17:19:04.305Z** coming from API. How can I know in which time zone it is, whether it UTC or EST or GMT etc...?

Any answers to find out the time zone of any timestamp will be of great help

Comment: The `Z` in the string basically tells you it's GMT / UTC ([not 100% the same](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z), but close enough).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but the above timestamp is in EST format. So I want to know how to find the timezone..

Comment: The time zone is UTC. If it was meant to be EST, whoever created the timestamp failed to include the correct time zone information.